# Wrong hostname after migrating FileRun to other sub-domain

Tags: php, mysql, migration

I have a running version of [FileRun](http://www.filerun.com).

When I move it to another subdomain (new: `fps.***.com` old: `demo.***.com`) it displays the error `This software application is registered to a different server hostname.`

But I have followed [this doc](https://docs.filerun.com/migrating) for migrating.

- I have changed the MySQL connection.
- I have exported the database and
  used `find & replace` to change all `demo` to `fps`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete the file `system/data/filerun.dat` to unregister the installation. You can afterwards re-register the installation from its control panel, via the new hostname.